# I have implemented the kafka with logstash input and elasticsearch output. its working fine in kibana.. I want to filter the data based on statuscode

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

This is kibana dashboard json Data.. Here i have to filter the based on response statuscode with in the message json data field..

```
{
  "_index": "rand-topic",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "ulF8uH0BK9MbBSR7DPEw",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
    "2021-12-14T10:27:56.956Z"
],
"@version": [
  "1"
],
"@version.keyword": [
  "1"
],
"message": [
  "{\"requestMethod\":\"GET\",\"headers\":{\"content-type\":\"application/json\",\"user-agent\":\"PostmanRuntime/7.28.4\",\"accept\":\"*/*\",\"postman-token\":\"977fc94b-38c8-4df4-ad73-814871a32eca\",\"host\":\"localhost:5600\",\"accept-encoding\":\"gzip, deflate, br\",\"connection\":\"keep-alive\",\"content-length\":\"44\"},\"body\":{\"category\":\"CAT\",\"noise\":\"purr\"},\"query\":{},\"requestUrl\":\"http://localhost:5600/kafka\",\"protocol\":\"HTTP/1.1\",\"remoteIp\":\"1\",\"requestSize\":302,\"userAgent\":\"PostmanRuntime/7.28.4\",\"statusCode\":200,\"response\":{\"success\":true,\"message\":\"Kafka Details are added\",\"data\":{\"kafkaData\":{\"_id\":\"61b871ac69be37078a9c1a79\",\"category\":\"DOG\",\"noise\":\"bark\",\"__v\":0},\"postData\":{\"category\":\"DOG\",\"noise\":\"bark\"}}},\"latency\":{\"seconds\":0,\"nanos\":61000000},\"responseSize\":193}"]},"sort[1639477676956]}
```

Expected output like this Here added the statuscode  field from message field

```
{
  "_index": "rand-topic",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "ulF8uH0BK9MbBSR7DPEw",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
 "fields": {
   "@timestamp": [
    "2021-12-14T10:27:56.956Z"
   ],
 "@version": [
    "1"
 ],
 "@version.keyword": [
    "1"
 ],
"statusCode": [
  200
],
"message": [
   "{\"requestMethod\":\"GET\",\"headers\":{\"content- 
 type\":\"application/json\",\"user- 
 agent\":\"PostmanRuntime/7.28.4\",\"accept\":\"*/*\",\"postman- 
 token\":\"977fc94b-38c8-4df4-ad73- 
 814871a32eca\",\"host\":\"localhost:5600\",\"accept- 
 encoding\":\"gzip, deflate, br\",\"connection\":\"keep- 
 alive\",\"content-length\":\"44\"},\"body\": 
 {\"category\":\"CAT\",\"noise\":\"purr\"},\"query\": {}, \"requestUrl\":\"http://localhost:5600/kafka\",\"protocol\":\"HTTP/1.1\",\"remoteIp\":\"1\",\"requestSize\":302,\"userAgent\":\"PostmanRuntime/7.28.4\",\"statusCode\":200,\"response\":{\"success\":true,\"message\":\"Kafka Details are added\",\"data\":{\"kafkaData\":{\"_id\":\"61b871ac69be37078a9c1a79\",\"category\":\"DOG\",\"noise\":\"bark\",\"__v\":0},\"postData\":{\"category\":\"DOG\",\"noise\":\"bark\"}}},\"latency\":{\"seconds\":0,\"nanos\":61000000},\"responseSize\":193}"
```

]},"sort": [1639477676956]}

Please help me how to configure logstash filter for statusCode

```
input {
  kafka {
    topics => ["randtopic"]
    bootstrap_servers => "192.168.29.138:9092"
  }
}

filter{
  mutate {
    add_field => { 
        "statusCode" => "%{[status]}" 
    }
  }
}

output {
 elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["192.168.29.138:9200"]
    index => "rand-topic"
    workers => 1
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 output {
  if [message][0][statusCode] == "200" {
     Do Somethings ....
    stdout { codec => ""}
  }
}
```

Comment: I need to filter based on statuscode from this response with in message field json (\"statusCode\":200,)and set it in filter configuration in log stash to display it as a separate field and let the message field as it is like a string not as a json in kibana


Now i have used it. but wont work

mutate {
        add_field => { 
            "statusCode" => "%{[status]}" 
        }
    }

Comment: try this :mutate {
    add_field => { "StatusCode" => "%[message][statusCode]" }
}

Comment: i tried it like 2 way.. but its not worked. 
mutate {
        add_field => { 
            "statusCode" => "%{[message][0][statusCode]}" 
        }
    }. and

mutate {
        add_field => { 
            "statusCode" => "%{[message][statusCode]}" 
        }
    }

Output

statusCode : %{[message][0][status]} 

Here status Code value is not set that variable. Its like returned given string